# Android Eclipse - How to get AppCompat for API 23

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I would like to get the AppCompat for API 23, currently what I see in Eclipse under Extras is rev 40, which I believe is for API 25. The issue with that is that it is too big and is making my app exceed 65K limit for methods. How do I get the AppCompat for API 23 ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't use eclipse

Comment: I got to realise that but I am very close to publishing my app, so cannot spare time to switch to Studio right now.

Comment: It's gonna have to happen some day. Better to do it before publishing. But I understand your situation. Good luck